# How to set initial useState value in React based on props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I currently set my `active` state to 0:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(0);
```

but I'm wondering how I can set the initial value to `null` if one of my component props: `isFilterMode` is true? So the initial state is "dynamic" based on the props?

Comment: `useState(props.isFilterMode ? null : 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like below

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(props.isFilterMode ? null : 0);
```

Or

using a callback function (`lazy initialisation`)

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(() => props.isFilterMode ? null : 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const Component = ({ isFilterMode }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(() => isFilterMode ? null : 0);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can define an expression with a return value as an argument for useState.
With a ternary operator like `props.isFilterMode ? null : 0` you would return `null` if the value of `props.isFilterMode` evaluates to true and 0 otherwise.
So in `useState` you would have:

```
  const [active, setActive] = useState(props.isFilterMode ? null : 0);
```

And like Amila suggested in the other answer you can use a callback as a parameter to useState and whatever is evaluated and returned from that callback would be your initial state using arrow functions you would do something like:

```
 const [active, setActive] = useState(() => props.isFilterMode ? null : 0);
```

or more explicitly but with longer code:

```
  const [active, setActive] = useState(() => { if(props.isFilterMode){ return null;} else { return 0;} } );
```